# Baseline aligned TextInputLayout and Spinner

Tags: android, xml, styles

I try to align spinner and edit text by baseline, but it doesn't work:

[image]

It start happen after update support library dependency from 24.1.1 to 24.2.1 (support-v4, appcompat-v7, design).
This is my xml code:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                style="@style/MailSpinner"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/spinner"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/spinner"
                android:baselineAlignedChildIndex="0">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="E-mail"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

MailSpinner style:

```
<style name="MailSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_textfield_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/spinner_tint</item>
    <item name="backgroundTintMode">src_atop</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please, add your `spinner_textfield_background` drawable and `spinner_tint` color resources.

Comment: @Sevastyan i have no access to this code anymore

Comment: That's bad. Although the baselines are aligned, the underline of the `Spinner` is not aligned to the underline of the `EditText`.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially the [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) isn't providing a baseline value to it's parent. We need to pipe the correct baseline of the `EditText` by extending `TextInputLayout`. This works for me, however, I'm not sure if the baseline would change due to other events from the `TextInputLayout`.

```
public class CTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    public CTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public int getBaseline()
    {
        EditText editText = getEditText();
        return editText.getPaddingTop() + editText.getBaseline();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this version is better when hint label is floating

```
public class CTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
public CTextInputLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public int getBaseline() {
    EditText editText = getEditText();
    return getMeasuredHeight() - (editText.getMeasuredHeight() - editText.getBaseline());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which aligns correctly when the TextInputLayout error text is set:

```
public class BaselineTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    public BaselineTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BaselineTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BaselineTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public int getBaseline() {
        EditText editText = getEditText();
        if (editText == null) { return 0; }
        return editText.getTop() + editText.getBaseline();
    }
}
```